# parseInt() = undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, integer

I need the datas of my array which are delivered as a string np, i
 programmed a while loop to get all my datas (120) rows after that i
 parsed them into an integer on the Browser Console i can see my rows
 121 but it says undefined???

pls see my code can u see where i made a mistake?

```
var signal_GW1 = dataFromAjax.data.data1.map(function(innerData){
   return innerData.map(function(row){
       return row[1];
   });
});

var i = 0;
while(i <= 120){
    var parsed = parseInt(dataFromAjax.data.data1[0][0][i]);
    console.log(parsed[i]);
    i++
}
```

result of browser console = 121 undefined

Comment: Change `i <= 120` to `i < 120`; arrays start at 0 so the 120th row is actually index 119

Comment: parsed is an int. not an array. `parsed[i]` is undefined since `parsed` will be the actual number you want

Comment: recommended way is to use for loop like `for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {}`

Comment: the array is dataFromAjax.data.data1[0][0][i]

Comment: my problem is the results are undefined so i cant calculate with them i need the results as an integer

Comment: @noSkill06s Yes, but `parsed[i]` in `console.log(parsed[i]);` is _undefined_ as the returned value from the `parseInt` function is a `Number` or `NaN` (which is technically a number too I think) and *not* an array, so the index `i` does not exist on something with the type of number.

Comment: But `parseInt` returns a *number*, for example `5`. What you are doing is `console.log(parsed[i])` which will be `5[0]`. The number doesn't have a property named zero (or any numeric property), so you get `undefined`.

Comment: so what should i do? sorry im a newbie

Comment: Remove the `[i]` from your console log statement and you should see your parsed numbers. Then simply use those. A number does not have items at an index, its just a number. If you look up an index on a number, it will be `undefined`, unlike when you do that on an array (that has something at that index, that is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove index property and use `length` of your array as condition in your `while` statement:

```
let arrayLength =  dataFromAjax.data.data1[0][0].length;
while(i < arrayLength ) {
    var parsed = parseInt(dataFromAjax.data.data1[0][0][i]); // 'parsed' variable 
                                                             // should be number
    console.log(parsed); // There is no need to use index property
    i++
}
```